# Setting category and other metadata via MediaWiki API

Tags: php, mediawiki-api

I have a lot of data that I want to upload to mediawiki with content and category metadata.
I found `Api.php?action=edit` for uploading and some bots framework in php
but I cant find any thing for setting the category.

Anybody know how to set category data with mediaWiki API or any framework?

Comment: I find [bootclasses](http://toolserver.org/~chris/highlight.php?d=chris/classes/&f=botclasses.php) framework
but I don't find any thing about insert category and sub Category in it

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add some page to a category, you would do it the same way as if you were editing the page manually: by adding code like `[[Category:Some Category]]` to the end of the article.